Subsystem dimension bound for the quantum relative entropy
I'm curious as to whether a statement of the following form can be proven:
$$
D(\rho_{AB} || \tau_{AB}) \leq D(\rho_{A}|| \tau_{A}) + |B|
$$
Where $D(\cdot || \cdot )$ is the standard quantum relative entropy, and $\rho, \tau$ are both density matrices. Is there any literature on the subject? Do counter examples exist?

What is $|B|$ ?

No. Let
$$\begin{align*}
\rho_{AB} &= (1-\varepsilon) |\phi^+\rangle \langle \phi^+| + \varepsilon |\psi^-\rangle \langle \psi^-| \\
\tau_{AB} &= \varepsilon |\phi^+\rangle \langle \phi^+| + (1-\varepsilon) |\psi^-\rangle \langle \psi^-|
\end{align*}
$$
Then $D(\rho_{AB}\| \tau_{AB}) = (1-2\varepsilon) \log \frac{1-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$, which goes to infinity as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Your hopeful upper bound, on the other hand, is just $|B| = 2$, since
$$
\rho_A = \tau_A = \frac12 I,
$$
and therefore $D(\rho_A \| \tau_A) = 0$.

Very insightful, thank you! Does the answer change if we give some more structure, like if $\tau_{AB} = \tau_A \otimes I_B/2^{|B|}$ ?

It does, because we have then $D(\rho_{AB} | \tau_A \otimes I / |B|) = \log|B| + D(\rho_{AB} | \tau_A \otimes I) = \log|B| + D(\rho_{A} | \tau_A) - H(\rho_{AB}) + H(\rho_A)$. Now $- H(\rho_{AB}) + H(\rho_A) = -H(B|A) \le \log|A|$, so you get the bound $D(\rho_{AB} | \tau_A \otimes I / |B|) \le D(\rho_{A} | \tau_A) + \log|AB|$

Fantastic, thank you so much :)
